# Highcharts - creating chart with same scale axis

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create combined chart with line and semi-circles with numerical x and y axis. I have a problem because I can't create the chart with axis in same scale. How every I try I always get different proportions of x and y scale.
Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/nje5cj6x/.

```
    var data = [
        [10, 100],
        [20, 150],
        [30, 200],
        [40, 250],
        [50, 300]
  ];
```

So, the container has the same width and height, both axis are the same, but still x and y axis are not the same proportions:
[Measured width and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm15e.jpg)

So, on this graph each point on the line should intersect with corresponding semi-circle at 90'. Can this be done?

Also, can I add some extra data in data var? For example, I'd like to pass variable r, besides x and y for radius? But if I do that, values are not calculated in same scale, so if I edit the code to:

```
chart.renderer.arc(point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop, point.r, point.r, -Math.PI, 0)
```

I get even worse result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the canvas element has the same width and height. However, there is more room used at the bottom for labels/legend that is used on the left for labels. As a result, the plot area has slightly different width and height. Since the x-axis and y-axis have the same range, 1 unit on the x-axis and 1 unit on the y-axis have slightly different lengths in canvas units. Instead of a rendering a circle on the plot area, you need to render a ellipse (that is almost a circle).

One solution is to push three points (left, top, right) for each arc into the circle_data array. Then use the plot area locations of those three points to render a path for an elliptical arc curve. For example...

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [
    [10, 100],
    [20, 150],
    [30, 200],
    [40, 250],
    [50, 300]
  ];

  var line_data = [];
  var circle_data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var xValue = data[i][1] / 2;
    var yValue = 0;
    var rValue = data[i][1] / 2;

    circle_data.push({
      x: xValue - rValue,
      y: yValue,
    });
    circle_data.push({
      x: xValue,
      y: yValue + rValue,
    });
    circle_data.push({
      x: xValue + rValue,
      y: yValue,
    });
    line_data.push({
      x: xValue,
      y: rValue
    });
  }

  $('#container2').highcharts({
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          useHTML: true,
          text: '&sigma; (MPa)'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        tickInterval: 20
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          useHTML: true,
          text: '&tau; (MPa)'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        tickInterval: 20
      },
      plotOptions: {
        line: {
          marker: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        // dataset za krivulju
        type: 'line',
        name: 'o3(MPa)',
        enableMouseTracking: true,
        data: line_data,
        point: {
          events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
              $('#row_' + this.index + ' > td').css("background-color", "yellow");
            },
            mouseOut: function() {
              $('#row_' + this.index + ' > td').css("background-color", "white");
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        // dataset za Mohrove kružnice
        visible: false,
        data: circle_data,
      }]
    },
    function(chart) {
      // crtanje Mohrovih kružnica
      for (var i = 0; 3 * i + 2 < chart.series[1].data.length; i++) {
        var point0 = chart.series[1].data[3 * i];
        var point1 = chart.series[1].data[3 * i + 1];
        var point2 = chart.series[1].data[3 * i + 2];
        var pathData = [
            "M",
            chart.plotLeft + point0.plotX,
            chart.plotTop + point0.plotY,
            "A",
            point2.plotX - point1.plotX,
            point2.plotY - point1.plotY,
            0,
            1,
            1,
            chart.plotLeft + point2.plotX,
            chart.plotTop + point2.plotY,
        ];
        chart.renderer.path(pathData)
          .attr({
            id: 'arc_' + i,
            fill: null,
            stroke: 'silver',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            data_id: i,
          })
          .on('mouseover', function() {
            $(this).css('stroke', 'red');
            $('#row_' + $(this).attr('data_id') + ' > td').css("background-color", "yellow");
          })
          .on('mouseout', function() {
            $(this).css('stroke', 'silver');
            $('#row_' + $(this).attr('data_id') + ' > td').css("background-color", "white");
          })
          .animate({
            'stroke-width': 3
          })
          .add();
      }
      chart.series[1].remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container2" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

Note that this solution works for any radius. The three data points in the circle_data array are computed from the radius. The render then computes the radius from the three corresponding plot area locations.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I need :)

Comment: Btw. is there a way to "trim" y axis so that it goes to say 180 but leaving everything in proportions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions are not the same because of bottom legend - it takes extra space. There is several options:

- [disable](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.enabled) legend
- make legend [floating](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.floating)
- set fixed width and height for axes: https://jsfiddle.net/nje5cj6x/2/

I think, the last solution is the best one, if you have fixed width and height for the chart. If not, I suggest to use second one.

Regarding points: of course, you can add additional params. However, I think you need to find relation `r`-value and `r`-pixels-value. Have you tried to use `chart.x/yAxis[index]` to pixels?

Comment: Great, even if Bobby Orndorff example works better for my case